# Bootstrap navbar collapse button on the big screens?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap navbar on my website, I need to make the navbar collapse button work on the big screens like in the mobile devices. How do I do that?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Default</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-toggle" aria-controls="navbar-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-toggle">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">A</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to understand how to post a good question so that the community can assist you. Please edit your post and add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any errors or logs you might get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `navbar-expand-*` class that will work for you

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link
rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Collapsing Always
<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button
    class="navbar-toggler"
    type="button"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"
  >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

Not Collapsing
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button
    class="navbar-toggler"
    type="button"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"
  >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```